# Melhor maneira de adicionar produto ao carrinho de compras

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um método que adiciona produto ao carrinho/session. Mas acho q estou utilizando muito código para isso e gostaria de fazer isso de uma forma melhor ou mais simplificada. Alguma dica?

```
public function addProduto($codigo, $quantidade, $preco) {


    if (!isset($_SESSION['carrinho']['produto'])) {
        $_SESSION['carrinho']['produto'][0] = array('codigo' => $codigo, 'quantidade' => $quantidade, 'preco' => $preco);
    } else {

        $codDuplicado = false;

        foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho']['produto'] as $key => $val) {

            if ($val['codigo'] == $codigo) {
                $codDuplicado = true;
                $_SESSION['carrinho']['produto'][$key]['quantidade'] += $quantidade;
            }
        }

        if (!$codDuplicado) {
            $indice = count($_SESSION['carrinho']['produto']);
            $_SESSION['carrinho']['produto'][$indice] = array('codigo' => $codigo, 'quantidade' => $quantidade, 'preco' => $preco);
        }
    }
}
```